# How can I create a zip file from array variable [fileName and FileContent]. using azure function or Azure logic app(with out any third part service)

Tags: azure, zip, azure-logic-apps, azure-function-app

How can I create a zip file from array variable [{"fileName":"", "FileContent" :""}]. using azure function or Azure logic app(with out any third part service)

Comment: Hi Srihari, please refer to the solution I provided below. If it helps your problem, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Comment: Hi, may I now if your problem was solved ? If still have any problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

For now, Compress/Zip files is not supported in logic app(if we do not use third party service), you could upvote for this feature on [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/31748887-compress-folder-to-archive) page.

But for azure function, we can implement it by code without third party service. I wrote a sample in my function, please refer to my function code below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            FileItem[] data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileItem[]>(requestBody);

            //As the request data you provided is a array with multiple file items, so here use foreach to loop each file item.
            foreach (FileItem item in data)
            { 
                log.LogInformation(item.fileName);
                log.LogInformation(item.FileContent);

                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                    {
                        var demoFile = archive.CreateEntry(item.fileName + ".txt");

                        using (var entryStream = demoFile.Open())
                        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
                        {
                            streamWriter.Write(item.FileContent);
                        }
                    }

                    //here I create the zip file in local, you can modify the code to create the zip file anywhere else you want.
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"D:\Temp\" + item.fileName + ".zip", FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    }
                }
            }

            string responseMessage = "complete";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }

    public class FileItem
    {
        public string fileName { get; set; }
        public string FileContent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Running the function above and request it in postman.
[image]
Then we can see the zip file was created in the path which I specified in code.
[image]